# xamarin.forms: app deep linking always opens browser, never app

Tags: forms, xamarin

I am trying to get app deep linking to work on android and ios. I followed this descr:

https://www.xamboy.com/2019/01/08/applinks-in-xamarin-forms/

I tried on android sofar, but no avail.

When I am calling the test link:

```
https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site= https://www.interiorcircle.de:&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls
```

I am receving an "OK" from what I interpretate this to be.

What I did on Android:

Main Activity:

```
namespace InteriorCircle.Droid
{
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
                  DataScheme = "https",
                  DataHost = "interiorcircle.de",
                  DataPathPrefix = "/hello",
                  AutoVerify = true,
                  Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable })]

    [Activity(Label = "Interior Circle", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

Putting file to our domain here:

https://interiorcircle.de/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Now when I click on a link "interiorcircle.de/hello/" it should open the xamarin.forms app, but it always goes to the brwoser and the browser says that this page is not available (which is true, there is not /hello/ on our host).

I also dont understand how the file from this link:
https://interiorcircle.de/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Knows how to respond to the /hello (while the ios file specifically hints to the /hello/

see here:
https://www.interiorcircle.de/.well-known/apple-app-site-association.json

(also this file added the .json in the end,.. not sure, if this should be there or no...)

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: According to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/app-linking), it seems that the namespace in your josn file is wrong and you can also check the package name and make sure that it's same as the package name in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT what namespaces are you refering to?

Comment: `"target" : { "namespace": "android_app", "package_name": "com.interiorcircle.interiorcircledroid",` Check this in your assetlinks.json and the namespace should use your project's.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT the namespaces are correct.

Comment: I noticed that i works on ios, just android doesnt play ball :(

Comment: You can check the package_name by double click the Properties->Android Manifest->Package Name